# Possible sockpuppet account?

Tags: discussion

https://serverfault.com/users/31965/rob-van-dam

100 consective day visits, > 400 votes, 0 questions, 0 answers.

Smells either like a sockpuppet, or a consciencous observer. No offense if it's the latter.

Comment: He's the Universe's way of balancing out people like me, who randomly wound up here from another SE site, and have zero questions, zero answers, and zero votes... (although I now have one *comment*...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks clean to my statistics; no anomalies. Just a user who likes to vote...

Answer (score 7):

I actually would think that this is encouraged.  It sounds like somebody who, rather than asking repeats of existing questions, is actively exploring the site/community.

I greatly prefer this than the multitude of easily-googleable questions that I see on SF, especially by those with very low reps.  (It's like trolling without the bad behavior!)

Caveat: Even the easily-googleable question scenario isn't that much of a problem...

Comment: I agree with your sentiments, but asking googlable questions is still encouraged, because when everyone else googles for them, we want them to find US, not Expert Sexchange (as so many of my search results end up with)

Comment: @Farseeker +1. I use the Firefox [Custom Google Search](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/13996/) add-on for this exact purpose -- filter out useless/unwanted sites.

Comment: Yes, it's encouraged if he's an honest citizen; but I agree, on the surface it's suspicious.

Answer (score 2):

He's young. He's a programmer. Probably just all excited about the wealth of knowledge to be found on SF. :)

The only thing that bothers my about this kind of behaviour is whether or not he can fairly judge a good or bad question or answer, considering it's not his field, and might be voting inappropriately.